# why does my pig query return the wrong values

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to work with the following dataset in pig
https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews/version/4?
I have been getting the wrong values from my querying the only reason I can think of is it is to do with missing data in the dataset
but I don't know if thats it or exactly why I get the wrong values

```
allWines = LOAD 'winemag-data_first150k.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray, country:chararray, description:chararray, designation:chararray, points:chararray, price:chararray, province:chararray, region_2:chararray, region_1:chararray, variety:chararray, winery:chararray);

allWinesNotNull = FILTER allWines BY price is not null;
allWinesNotNull2 = FILTER allWinesNotNull BY points is not null;
allWinesPriceSorted = ORDER allWinesNotNull2 BY price;
allWinesPriceTop5Sorted = LIMIT allWinesPriceSorted  5;
allWinesPricePoints = FOREACH allWinesPriceTop5Sorted GENERATE id, price;
DUMP allWinesPricePoints;

DESCRIBE allWinesPricePoints;
```

The actual results I get are
(56203,   buttered toast and spice flavors that are wrapped into a creamy texture. Should hold for a year or two.")
(61341,   sweet tannins. The fresh acidity gives it an extra boost. Give it time. Best 2007–2012.")
(16417,  Chardonnay is also known)
(115384,  almonds and vanilla)
(136804,  almonds and vanilla)

I think the output should be
(56203, 23)
(61341, 30)
(16417, 16)
(115384, 250)
(136804, 250)

I would have expected the second value to be numeric and in the price column

Comment: It looks like the `description` field can contain commas, which might cause your data to be parsed oddly.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as follow:

```
allWines = LOAD 'winemag-data_first150k.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:chararray, country:chararray, description:chararray, designation:chararray, points:chararray, price:chararray, province:chararray, region_2:chararray, region_1:chararray, variety:chararray, winery:chararray);

--comments
--add below foreach to generate the values this will help you out to parse data correctly
--generate column in the same order as it is in the text file
allWines= FOREACH allWines GENERATE
id AS id,
country AS country,
description AS description,
designation AS designation,
points AS points,
price AS price, 
province AS provience,
region_2 AS region_2,
region_1 AS region_1,
variety AS variety,
winery AS winery;

allWinesNotNull = FILTER allWines BY price is not null;
allWinesNotNull2 = FILTER allWinesNotNull BY points is not null;
allWinesPriceSorted = ORDER allWinesNotNull2 BY price;
allWinesPriceTop5Sorted = LIMIT allWinesPriceSorted  5;
allWinesPricePoints = FOREACH allWinesPriceTop5Sorted GENERATE id, price;
DUMP allWinesPricePoints;
DESCRIBE allWinesPricePoints;
```

Hope this will help you out.
let me know in case of any concern.